# I want to include a generated directory in a Maven site

Tags: maven

I'm using Pi Test to generate some reports. I'd like to publish it as part of the standard Maven site. It creates some HTML files in `target/pit-reports`, with an index page at `target/pit-reports/201403161013/index.html'. How can I include this in the published site?

Comment: The best is to change the target folder for your pit-reports to `target/site/pit-reports/..` and than create a link on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of pitest-maven version 1.1.6, a new report goal is available for including the pit report in a maven site.  Documentation on how to use it is at the bottom of the quickstart guide -- http://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/

Answer (score 0):

```
<reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/pit-reports</reportsDirectory>
<timestampedReports>false</timestampedReports>
```

Comment: Alex can you please extend a little bit on this ? I don't understand where `reportsDirectory` should be placed. Thx in advance.